# Круг в круге другого цвета

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать такой слайдер-курсор?

[image]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Не надо удалять вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border: 1em solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 1em;
  position: relative;
}

div::before, div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200%;
  z-index: -1;
}

div::before {
  right: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

div::after {
  left: 100%;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: это должен быть курсор слайдера(type="range")

Comment: @megohow760, ну значит надо как-то с его псевдоэлементами играться... Курсор - это с смысле ползунок?

Comment: да .......................

Comment: @megohow760, вот тут целая статья есть: https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/